Determine the rank of Matrix $A$ depending on $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$
Determine the rank of Matrix $A$ depending on $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$:
$A := 
\begin{bmatrix}0 & \alpha & \beta \\ -\alpha & 0 & \gamma \\ -\beta & -\gamma & 0\end{bmatrix}$.
Now I used the Gaussian algorithm to transform $A$ to row echolon form. I calculated the normaled and the not normaled version:
$A' = \begin{bmatrix}\alpha & 0 & -\gamma \\ 0 & \alpha & \beta \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$
As far as I see there are three cases concerning the dependence of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ on the rank:
Case a) $\alpha = 0, \beta = 0, \gamma = 0 \Longrightarrow \text{rank}(A') = 0$
Case b) $\alpha = 0, \beta \in \mathbb{R}\setminus0, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}\setminus0 \Longrightarrow \text{rank}(A') = 2$
Case c) $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\setminus0, \beta \in \mathbb{R}, \gamma \in \mathbb{R} \Longrightarrow \text{rank}(A') = 2$
Is this correct so far?
Now $A''$ is the normaled matrix of $A'$:
$A'' = \begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{\gamma}{\beta} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{\beta}{\alpha} \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$
In $A''$ the rank is always $2$, independently of $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$. Where is the mistake?

Division assumes that the quantity being divided by is nonzero. (i.e. in $A''$ you have $\alpha$ and $\beta$ appearing in denominators, so somewhere along the line you assumed that they are nonzero)

In addition to what @TheoC. said, there's also something odd with case b): when $\alpha=0$, $A'$ has two columns which are identically null, so its rank shouldn't be greater than $1$.

Do you know that such a skew-symmetric matrix is the matrix associated to the cross product with a fixed vector $V$ : $U  \to  V \times U$ as explained for example in this answer of mine here ? This gives a geometrical proof that its rank (= dimension of range space) is in general equal to two.

To obtain $A'$, you assumed that $\alpha\ne0$ for your row reduction. So you cannot conclude anything about the case $\alpha=0$ from that. This means that you are correct to conclude that the rank is $2$ when $\alpha\ne0$.
When $\alpha=0$, the echelon form is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-\beta&-\gamma&0\\ 0&0&\beta\\0&0&\gamma\end{bmatrix}
$$
If $\beta\ne0$ then this has rank $2$. And when $\beta=0$, the two gammas (if nonzero) also make it rank 2.
In summary the rank of $A$ is $2$ unless $A=0$.
Another way to notice this is that $A$ is (complex) diagonalizable with eigenvalues $0$ and $\pm i\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2}$. So $A$ has rank at most two because of the eigenvalue $0$, and it maps the $2$-dimensional space spanned by the eigenvectors of the two nonzero eigenvalues onto itself. Hence the rank of $A$ is $2$ if $A\ne0$.

Thank you for this explanation. I've understood it pretty well.
